# Resolving Images after URL Changes - .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have done few changes and unable to get my images resolved correctly.

Old = `http://www.domain.com/dir/images/*.jpg`

New = `http://www.domain.com/old_dir/images/*.jpg`

I am using the following RewriteRule,

```
RewriteRule ^dir/images/(.*)\.jpg$ old_dir/images/$1\.jpg [R=301]
```

Doesn't work, any pointers on how to get to work the images resolved correctly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your

```
RewriteRule ^dir/images/(.*)\.jpg$ old_dir/images/$1\.jpg [R=301]
```

should be

```
RewriteRule ^/dir/images/(.*)\.jpg$ /old_dir/images/$1\.jpg [R=301]
```

The `^` signifies an anchor at the beginning, and your anchor followed by the `dir` excludes the required leading `/`

See the [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for details.

**Debugging Steps**

As far as specific steps for debugging you could try:

1. `RewriteRule ^.*$ /test.html [R=301]` to make sure the rewriting engine is actually working.
2. If that works, you can try an absolute uri instead of a regex one: `RewriteRule ^/dir/images/image1.jpg$ /old_dir/images/image1.jpg [R=301]`
3. If that works, you can try tweaking the regular expressions to make sure you're getting them right.

Are there any indications that the re-writing is happening at all?  Is the URL in the browser being rewritten at all?

Comment: Updated with some trouble shooting steps.